# Mobile Mapping/Form App Questions

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile, mapping, kml

I'm a newbie mobile programmer with an idea for a mobile mapping form.  I have plenty of experience programming other web-based apps, but haven't done anything mobile yet.  Without going into exhaustive detail about the app, I was hoping to get some responses to the general questions below.  I would prefer to develop with HTML5, CSS & Javascript to ease deployment on multiple platforms, but am open to developing in other environments to achieve the results I need.

1. I need to have the ability to create spatial data, both by GPS collection and by drawing on screen over maps, and the ability to export for use in other desktop GIS programs.  I know this is possible based on other apps that already do it, but Im unsure how they are accomplishing it.  I presume they are simply logging location points and having those points written to an XML file.  Is this correct?  Does anyone know of any documentation online that I could be directed to? If it's simply a KML that is being created on the mobile device, I believe exporting would be fairly easy by translating to CSV and importing to other programs.
2. Regarding data collection/creation, I also need the ability to collect/create while offline.  I believe I can use something like the Bad Elf GPS for offline data collection (www.bad-elf.com), so my question is more in regards to storage.  If creating data offline, can it be stored locally on the mobile device using sqlLite and then exported to a SQL database when back online?  If so, would this allow me to view the data Im creating live on-screen as it is being created?

Lastly, any thoughts on developing in HTML5/CSS/Javascript?  I've considered using Flash Builder as well, but don't own the current copy (4.6) yet, still on 4.0.

If anyone knows of any online documentation that would give me some insight into mobile data collection/creation it would be greatly helpful.

Thanks in advance to the responses.

Zach